# codeigniter 3 404 not found except default controller Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, ubuntu

I'm very new to CodeIgniter actually this is my first project in CI. I have setup base project. location is :

```
   /home/mypc/workspace/myci
```

I'm Using ubuntu 14.04 LTS, CI version is 3. I have setup virtual host as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName myci.dev

    DocumentRoot /home/mypc/workspace/myci

    <Directory /home/mypc/workspace/myci/>
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

and entry in /etc/hosts is

```
  127.0.0.1 myci.dev
```

This is config.php

```
   $config['base_url'] = 'http://myci.dev/';
   $config['index_page'] = '';
   $config['uri_protocol']  = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

This is .htaccess file

```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This is routes.php

```
   $route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
   $route['404_override'] = '';
   $route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
   $route['footer/(:any)'] = 'footer';
```

Now, when ever I visit homepage, it works fine. URL is
http://myci.dev
http://myci.dev/index.php

both URL works fine. However any other URL except default does not work. It always returns 404 error. I have searched and tried many things. Please help me. File name is "Footer.php" and class name is "Footer".

Comment: Why you are using `$route['footer/(:any)'] = 'footer';`. Can you please tell.

Comment: If you will use above route then every function of footer routed to index of footer controller.

Comment: It is supposed to be handled like that.. or as I was told.. ;). But as I said I'm not able to access it right now. And I have no idea why.. :(

Comment: can you paste what other url you are trying